# Firebase Auth Custom Claims for the app with team management

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

My product has a team feature like Asana or Clickup. Each member has its own role over his company. How would you design custom claims? A user should be able to join multiple teams.

My idea is

```
getAuth()
 .setCustomUserClaims(uid, {
  teams: [
    {name: "Company A", role: "admin"},
    {name: "Company B", role: "basic"}
  ]
})
 .then(() => {
 });
```

It requires a loop when checking a user's team and role. Are there better design? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just an alternative, if a user can only have 1 role per team then you could use an object instead `{ teams: { company1Id: 'admin' } }` so you won't have to iterate over the array to find user's role in a specific company.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, a user can have only one role in a company. Do you suggest doing something like this https://i.imgur.com/YJs9mSp.png id: role? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it might make reading/writes roles a bit easier in code. e.g. `role = teams[teamId].role` instead of `teams.find(t => t.id === teamId).role`

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thank you very much for the answer! Can you please suggest more? In the application, the company administrator will also have the ability to change the role of a user who belongs to his company. Also in the company settings, it will be possible to see all users who belong to the company. Please tell me, if I use custom claims, will it be possible to implement such functionality?

Comment: Yes, that possible.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thanks for the answer! In this case, I will then have to create documents for each user in the firestore? So that I can then receive data about who belongs to my company